# How to catch errors with IO::File perl

Tags: perl, file-io

Normally you'd do:

```
open( my $fh, "+<", "$thefile.txt") or die "Could not open $thefile.txt $!\n";
```

but with IO::File you do (from docs):

```
$fh = new IO::File;
if ($fh->open("< file")) {
    print <$fh>;
    $fh->close;
}
```

Does IO::File automatically throw errors/die if there was a problem opening the file? How would one go about it when using this module?

Mostly concerned with logging, how would you log out a 'good' error message like 'No such file or directory'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [`IO::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html):

> CONSTRUCTOR
>
> - `new ( FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]] )`
>
>   Creates an `IO::File`. If it receives any parameters, they are passed to the method [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html); if the open fails, the object is destroyed. Otherwise, it is returned to the caller.

Therefore, you can use [`or die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) statements just like you normally do:

```
use IO::File;

my $fh = IO::File->new('notfound.txt') or die "Can't open: $!";
```

Outputs:

```
Can't open: No such file or directory at script.pl line 5.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$fh->open("< file")` will be false if it cannot open the file.  So just add an `else`:

```
$fh = new IO::File;
if ($fh->open("< file")) {
    print <$fh>;
    $fh->close;
}
else {
    die("Cannot open file.  Reason: $!");
}
```

Comment: but is there any way to get the reason for not being able to open?

Comment: @a7omiton IO::File uses the standard Perl `open` function behind the scenes, so failure to open will set the `$!` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 open( my $fh, "+<", "thefile.txt") or die "Could not open thefile.txt $!\n";
```

Remove $ sign from thefile.txt. You are not storing your file name in a variable.

you can use

```
$file = 'thefile.txt';
open( my $fh, "<", "$file") or die "Could not open $file $!\n"
```

In die the "$!" would show the error message as "No such file or directory"